# Translate while loop to do while

Tags: java

Very simple but I cannot seem to figure it out, I simply need to translate the while loops into do-while. Objective is to print 1-9 and 9-1 one as such "1,22,333,4444" etc. Thank you if you help me!

```
int y = 1;
int x = 1;
while (x < 10) {
    y = 1;
    while (y <= x) {
        y++;
        System.out.print(x + "");
    }
    System.out.println();
    x++;
}

int a = 9;
int b = 1;
while (a >=1) {
    b = 1;
    while (b<= a) {
        b++;
        System.out.print(a + "");
    }
    System.out.println();
    a--;
}
```

My attempt prints 1-9 but as single numbers and infinitely runs, but does not print anything after 9 the first time.

```
int c = 1;
int d =1;
do { System.out.print(c +"");
c++;
System.out.println();
}
while (c<10);{
    y=1;
    while (d<=c);
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: You are missing a second "do" statement. The 2nd while statement is actually a while loop that does not execute any code as the content of the variables does not change it is equivalent to "while(true);" (also you don't seem to change the value of d ever and y is not defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we are doing your homework...

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c = 1;
        do { 
            int d =1;
            do{
                System.out.print(c);
                d++;
            } while (c>=d);
            System.out.println("");
        c++;        
        }
        while (c<10);
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it, but I did say I don't expect you to do it for me. I'm one of the few who realizes that I actually need to know how to do it. What I don't understand is I just tried something identical to that as far as I know and it didn't work, it counted infinitely. A brace in the wrong spot probably caused that right?

Comment: Your infinite loop certainly comes from here: 
    while (d<=c);
You have a while that does nothing, so condition is never changed. If d<=c it will be infinite...

Comment: Ahh that makes sense now. I appreciate your help. I know it was a trivial beginner mistake but everyone starts somewhere right? I'll be sure to contribute to the community as I learn more. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic usage:

```
x=1;
do{ 
    //hello
    x++; 
} while(x<=10);
```

Apply it as you need. We can't really do your homework.

Comment: I understand and appreciate that, and I don't expect you to, I'm just looking for guidance in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a nested `do-while`.

```
int x = 1;

do {
   int p = 0;
   do {
      System.out.print(x); 
   }
   while(p < x)
   System.out.println();
   x++;
}
while(x < 10)
```

But I should probably add a `for` loop would make a lot more sense here:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    for(int p = 0; p < x; p++)
    {
        System.out.print(x);  
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to run in infinite loop just use:

```
    do {
        int c = 1;
        do {
            System.out.println(c);
            c++;

        } while (c < 10);
    } while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will run infinitely and print your desired strings:

```
        StringBuilder result1= new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder result2 = new StringBuilder();

    do
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                result1.append(i);
            }
            result1.append(",");
        }

        for(int i = 9; i > 0; i--)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                result2.append(i);
            }
            result2.append(",");
        }

        System.out.println(result1);
        System.out.println(result2);
    }while(true);
```